# MySQL trigger working on one table but not the other

Tags: mysql

I have created a mysql trigger to update on insert a value from another table:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `CourseCode`//
CREATE TRIGGER `CourseCode` BEFORE INSERT ON `race`
FOR EACH ROW  BEGIN
SET NEW.Course_Code = (
    SELECT 
        course_code 
    from 
        tb_course 
    where 
        tb_course.course_name = NEW.course_name
)
END
//
```

This works perfectly. It returns the 4 character code for the course_name based on the tb_course table.

What I'm trying to do is the exact same thing in another table, I copy and paste the trigger and rename the trigger and the table (field names and types are also identical) it but it won't work:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `CourseCode2`//
CREATE TRIGGER `CourseCode2` BEFORE INSERT ON `fields`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
SET NEW.Course_Code = (
    SELECT 
        course_code 
    from 
        tb_course 
    where 
        tb_course.course_name = NEW.course_name
)
END    
//
```

However this results in null values. I've tried replacing New.Course_name with a string (i.e. tb_course.course_name="String") and that updates that static value fine so the trigger appears to be working but either it isn't matching the select statement in this table for or it's not setting the Course_Code field...

Is there any sort of debugging you can suggest to figure this out? It's driving me nuts and I don't know what to do to diagnose the problem.

Cheers

Comment: *Why* are you doing this?  If `course_name` is sufficient to identify unique records in `tb_course` (which must be the case for these triggers to work), then simply use that as your foreign key in the other tables.  Storing the `course_code` in addition violates [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Comment: Hi, to be honest because I have no idea what a foreign key is... I've sloppily self taught my mysql knowledge to get something working. I will do some reading about foreign keys and see if this helps me.

Thanks

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying now. I have also found an error in the data being entered into my fields table that was causing the trigger to fail (whitespace at the beginning that I wasn't noticing) so that explains my original problem. Thanks for the reply, I will do a bit of tweaking and start using a few foreign keys instead of my triggers eventually.

Comment: In reality, many applications use surrogate keys e.g. `course_code`, rather than natural ones e.g. `course_name` (for one thing, it enables key values to be changed without updating child tables): that is, to adhere to 3NF, you would store only `course_code` and not `course_name` in your child tables. How is this done? Usually the application knows the relevant `course_code` at the time of data insertion—and therefore provides it to the database directly in the `INSERT` statement; if it is not known, one can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/insert-select.html) to get it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is wrong with the second trigger.

However, the 'debugging' part i can maybe help with.

A search of the 'net' will return various software (paid for) that will allow single step debugging. Rather than pay for stuff, all i want is 'print' statements from inside stored function procedures and triggers.

a quick search lead me to someone who has done all the work already.

[Debugging Stored Procedures in MySql](https://github.com/CaptTofu/Stored-procedure-debugging-routines)

I have just set it up in MySql and tried it and it works fine.

Here is some sample code, based on your trigger and the output i got.

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `testmysql`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `CourseCode`$$
CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'test'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `CourseCode` BEFORE INSERT ON `race` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        DECLARE v_course_code INT; 
        DECLARE v_course_title VARCHAR(255);

    CALL procLog("line 12: Entering CourseCode");
    SELECT 
        course_code, course_title
        INTO
        v_course_code, v_course_title
    FROM 
        tb_course 
    WHERE 
        tb_course.course_name = NEW.course_name;

    SET NEW.course_code = v_course_code;

        CALL procLog(CONCAT("line_22: ", v_course_title, " code: ", NEW.course_code));
        CALL procLog("line 24: Exiting CourseCode");
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Query:**

```
CALL setupProcLog();

INSERT INTO `race` (course_name, race_info)
VALUES ('learn_it_02', 'this is another test');

CALL cleanup('query end');
```

**procLog output:**

entrytime            connection_id  msg

---

2014-02-23 12:32:21              5  line 12: Entering CourseCode
2014-02-23 12:32:21              5  line_22: Learn It Course 02 code: 2
2014-02-23 12:32:21              5  line 24: Exiting CourseCode
2014-02-23 12:32:21              5  cleanup() query end

Ok, a little clumsy maybe but it will help with debugging 'stored' programs.

I will be using it from now on.